# Makefile - fail if directory doesn't exist - cross platform

Tags: makefile, directory, installation, cross-platform

I'm writing the installation part of a Makefile and I'd like to check if the project was built, and if not installation should fail. For that purpose I'd like to check if certain directories exist and if not - fail with an appropriate error (something like "please run make all first").

I also want this Makefile to work on Linux, Windows (mingw) and MacOS.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using GNU make or a version of make that supports [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-order_002donly-prerequisites), there is a natural solution. Declare these directories as order-only prerequisites of your install target:

```
install: | $(DIRS)
    <install recipe>

$(DIRS):
    @echo "please run make all first" && exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the mingw make, then the answer sholud be the same for all platforms:

```
dirs-exist:
        test -d dir1 || echo Run make install first && exit 2
        test -d dir2
```

In For the first directory we use the or operator to print a message if the test fails.  However, even though we successfully printed the message, we want the entire line to fail, so we exit with an error code of 2.
The above logic could be applied to each directory if you want to  have the message in all cases.  If you have a lot of directories, a loop like the following might work

```
test_dirs:
    for d in dir1 dir2; do if test \!  -d $$d; then echo run make install first; exit 2; fi
```

The only complexity would be if you needed this to work with nmake and cmd on windows; sounds like that's not an issue here.

Comment: Thanks! How can I output an error message if one of those directories doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

@SamHarman's answer is correct (and he posted earlier), so you should accept his answer as soon as he fixes his first example.   In any case, I thought I'd post this as well, which is a slightly shorter and slightly more confusing version of the same thing... :-)

```
DIRS=dir1 dir2 dir3

checkdirs:
        [[ 1 ${DIRS:%= && -d %} ]] || ( echo "uh oh..." && false );

.PHONY: checkdirs
```